# Uploading file with asp.net not working

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am trying to upload a file through ASPX using a HTML form and trying to catch my file in codebehind.

My HTMLform right now is

```
 <form id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" id="myFile" name="myFile" />
      <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUpload" OnClick="btnUploadClick" Text="Upload" />
 </form>
```

And my method in codebehind:

```
protected void btnUploadClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files["myFile"];

    //check file was submitted
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        string title = "title";
        string message = "this worked";
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), title, "alert('" + message + "');", true);
        string fname = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~/App_Data/", fname)));
    }
    else
    {
        string title = "title";
        string message = "nothing happened";
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), title, "alert('" + message + "');", true);
    }
}
```

So whenever i submit my HTML form, I always get the alert that nothing happened. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: get rid of your form tag, its not needed as you have onclick function, unless there is a reason you need the form tag?

Answer (score 1):

Your existing code actually requires that you have a `runat="server"` tag on your `<form>` element for your code to actually work :

```
<form id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" runat="server">
    <!-- Content -->
</form>
```

**Master Pages and Nested Forms**

However based on your comment, it sounds like you already have a parent `<form>` element present within your Master Page. If that is the case, then consider adding your `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute to that parent `<form>` element instead :

```
<!-- This should be your Master Page form -->
<form id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" runat="server">
     <!-- Content -->
</form>
```

Then you should be able to ignore your inner-child form as it will fall under the one generated by your Master Page. Once you add that, it should work as expected :

[image]

Comment: My problem when I add the runat="server" i get the `A page can have only one server-side Form tag.` error. This is because my site.Master has a form(the default one). Do you know of a work around to this?

Comment: It should be okay then. I didn't see any code that would indicate that you had it defined elsewhere. Consider replacing this child `<form>` element and just set your `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on your main `<form>` that contains your `runat="server"` tag.